# use CSOM for the GetListAndView WebService for multiple lists/views

Tags: 2010, javascript, csom

I know how to use `lists.asmx?op=GetListAndView` to get list and view details.

I'm trying to do the same using CSOM. And, to keep it efficient, I wanted to make one call for multiple lists/views. But there is a possibility that a list or view doesn't exist so I should be able to check that for each list/view.

This is what I have so far.

```
var listsToCheck = [
    { "listName" : "....", "listGUID" : "....", "viewName" : "....", "viewGUID" : "...." },
    { "listName" : "....", "listGUID" : "....", "viewName" : "....", "viewGUID" : "...." },
    { "listName" : "....", "listGUID" : "....", "viewName" : "....", "viewGUID" : "...." },
    { "listName" : "....", "listGUID" : "....", "viewName" : "....", "viewGUID" : "...." },
    { "listName" : "....", "listGUID" : "....", "viewName" : "....", "viewGUID" : "...." }
];

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    for(var i = 0; i < listsToCheck.length; ++i)
    {
        var listToCheck = listsToCheck[i];

        listToCheck.list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listToCheck.listName);
        clientContext.load(listToCheck.list);
        clientContext.load(listToCheck.list, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');

        listToCheck.view = listToCheck.list.get_views().getByTitle(listToCheck.viewName);
        clientContext.load(listToCheck.view);
    }

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function()
    {
        // SEE NOTE BELOW
        for(var i = 0; i < listsToCheck.length; ++i)
        {
            var listToCheck = listsToCheck[i];

            console.log("user has edit permission: " + listToCheck.list.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems));
            console.log("view details: " + listToCheck.view.get_htmlSchemaXml());
        }
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, function()
        {
            alert("error");
        }));
}, "sp.js");
```

- if all the lists and views exist then the code works
- but if any list or view doesn't exist then the entire thing errors

I'd also like to get field details, particularly the field type, but I can't figure out how to add that to here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `SP.ExceptionHandlingScope` as a 'batch try/catch' which will not cause your entire operation to fail if just one call fails on the server after you send it off.

Something like this (note that I have not personally used this function, but it is documented (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411960%28v=office.14%29.aspx)):

```
var e = new SP.ExceptionHandlingScope(clientContext);
var s = e.startScope();
for(var i = 0; i < listsToCheck.length; ++i)
{
    var listToCheck = listsToCheck[i];
    //try
    var t = e.startTry();
    listToCheck.list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listToCheck.listName);
    clientContext.load(listToCheck.list);
    clientContext.load(listToCheck.list, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');

    listToCheck.view = listToCheck.list.get_views().getByTitle(listToCheck.viewName);
    clientContext.load(listToCheck.view);

    t.dispose();

    //catch
    var c = e.startCatch();
    // Do something on the server...

    //finally
    var f = e.startFinally();
    // Finally do something on the server...
    f.dispose();

    //End Exception-Handling Scope
    s.dispose();

}
```

For the fields, the `SchemaXml` on the view should have a `<viewfields>` element that you can parse out. otherwise you should also be able to access the `fields` property of the SP.List object.

Answer (score 1):

XMLNode `abc= clientcontext.GetListandView(List Name)` will give you views details in form of XML. Now you need to parse and get all the view GUID and pass it to `GetListItems()`.

```
WS_Lists.Lists client = new WS_Lists.Lists();
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Slogin1.Username, Slogin1.Password);
            System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
            System.Xml.XmlElement viewFields =
                xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
            System.Xml.XmlElement queryOptions =
                xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
            query.InnerXml = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />" + "<Value Type=\"Counter\">0</Value></Gt></Where>";
            viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" + "<FieldRef Name =\"fRecurrence\" />" + "<FieldRef Name =\"RecurrenceID\" />" + "<FieldRef Name =\"RecurrenceData\" />";               
            XmlNode listItems = client.GetListItems(ListTitle, "View Guid", query, viewFields, "0", queryOptions, null);
```